# Leray-Hirsch for HOMOLOGY?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, spectral-sequences

Let $E\to B$ be a fibre bundle. The [Leray-Hirsch theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leray-Hirsch_theorem) states under suitable assumptions, the cohomology of $E$ is an $H^*(B)$-module generated by suitable cohomology classes in $E$.

Is there any analogous results for the homology of $E$? Any reference?

Comment: It's automatic that the cohomology of E is a module over the cohomology of B.  The point of Leray-Hirsch is that it is sometimes free.

Comment: Sorry. I was stupid to miss this condition.

Comment: A version of the Leray-Hirsch for homology is as follows: let $p:E\to B$ be a Serre fibration with $B$ connected and let $A$ be an abelian group. Assume that $p_\ast :H_\ast(F,A)\to H_\ast(E,A)$ is injective where $F$ is the fiber over some point of $B$, then $H_n(E,A)\cong \bigoplus_{i+j=n} H_i(B,H_j(F,A))$. The free module part is a bit tricky since, although the cohomology with coefficients in $A$ is always an $A$-algebra as long as $A$ is a commutative ring, the homology is not necessarily an $A$-coalgebra.

Comment: Is that isomorphism true or is just true up to group extension?